# Partial SPA App, history navigation renders JSON in view port

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

We have a pretty large application being built in progressive mode so we have performance critical pages are migrated to SPA (react, redux, react-router([Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router))) while other pages are served in established legacy app.

All SPA pages are navigated with [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) and non SPA via html anchor.

Our SPA pages support full page refresh and rendered from server. For normal route navigation same page url with ajax mode send us json data that is saved in the store.

Some times, particularly in case of clean cached mode, when we navigate in this pattern:

1. Start from SPA page (Server-side Rendered)
2. Navigate to another SPA page (Async call gets JSON and updates store to update page rendering)
3. Navigate to non-SPA page (conventional browser navigation)
4. Hitting browser back button

Problem: Browser renders JSON text in view port acquired for step 2

We tried to overcome this issue via `Cache-Control: 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'` header for route navigation async calls but it did not fixed it well.

How should we deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete header needed:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0 ");
```

have you tried this complete solution ?

Comment: I am missing `Expires` here. :)